# Como faço parar organizar a tabuada em while?

Tags: c, while

Como faço parar organizar essa tabuada ? Soma, subtração e multiplicação respectivamente ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int i=0, num=0;

printf ("Digite um n£mero: ");
scanf ("%d",&num);

printf ("\n");

while (i<=9){
    i++;
    printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", i, num, num+i);

    printf ("%d - %d = %d\n", i, num, i-num);

    printf ("%d X %d = %d\n", i, num, num*i);
}
}
```

Comment: como assim organizar?

Comment: Quando executo ele fica tudo bagunçado tipo 1+1, 1-1, 1x1, 2+1, 2+1, 2-1, 2x1 ... e assim vai ate o 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apenas substitua os '\n's do primeiro e segundo printf por '\t's, desta maneira ele não fará a quebra de linha, que no caso é o '\n', e ainda dará um tab, no caso o \t, (equivalente a quatro espaços).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i=0, num=0;

    printf ("Digite um n£mero: ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);

    printf ("\n");

    while ( i <= 9 )
    {
        i++;
        printf ("%d + %d = %d\t", i, num, num+i);

        printf ("%d - %d = %d\t", i, num, i-num);

        printf ("%d X %d = %d\n", i, num, num*i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Neste caso o output ficara assim:
[image: Neste caso o output ficara assim:]

outro modo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
    int i = 0, num = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    printf ("Digite um número: ");
    scanf (" %d", &num);

    printf ("\nAdição:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i <= 9; i++ )
        printf ("%d + %d = %d\n", i, num, num+i);

    printf ("\nSubtração:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i <= 9; i++ )
        printf ("%d - %d = %d\n", i, num, i-num);

    printf ("\nMultiplicação\n");
    for ( i = 0; i <= 9; i++ )
        printf ("%d X %d = %d\n", i, num, num*i);

    return 0;
}
```

Desta forma o output ficará sequencial, adicionei a biblioteca locale.h para poder usar acento, o comando `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` é o comando que permite os acentos BR posam ser usados, a imagem deste output é esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu muito certo não kk continuo 1+1, 1-1, 1x1, 2+1, 2+1, 2-1, 2x1 ... so q com espaços, quero que ele fique algo do tipo 1+ate o 10, 1-ate 10, 1xate o 10

Comment: cara editei a resposta, espero ter ajudado, caso contrario explique um pouco melhor o que você deseja, não esta muito claro, faça um exemplo correto de output saca, isso ajudará.

Comment: vi agora a edição, ficou direitinho agora <3 brigadão